# How to get ansible 'become' user in included file?

Tags: sudo, ansible

Using ansible 1.9. Inventory:

```
my.host ansible_ssh_user=FIRSTUSER
```

Playbook:

```
- hosts: my.host
  roles:
    - myrole
```

Role tasks file:

```
- include: tasks.yml

- include: tasks.yml
  become: true
  become_user: SECONDUSER
```

In `tasks.yml` I'm trying to print out the user who is currently running that file. The first time it should print `FIRSTUSER` and the second time it should print `SECONDUSER`. But no matter what I try (`ansible_ssh_user`, `ansible_user_id`, `ansible_env`), it always prints `FIRSTUSER`, even though the second time `tasks.yml` is run it's run as `SECONDUSER`.

How do I print the user that is currently running `tasks.yml`?

If in `tasks.yml` I include a task `file: dest=~/tmp state=directory'`, using the user-relative path `~/tmp`, it correctly puts it at `/home/FIRSTUSER/tmp` the first time and `/home/SECONDUSER/tmp` the second time. So it's working correctly, but I can't get the user from a variable within `tasks.yml` so that I can conditionally execute certain things for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vars like `ansible_ssh_user`, `ansible_user_id`, `ansible_env` etc. are provided by the setup module. The setup module is by default executed as first task of the playbook, which is the *GATHERING FACTS* task you should see during play. That should explain why these variables do not correlate to what you have specified in your include statements.

You should be able to fetch these vars again in your included tasks file by running the setup module again. But be aware this would permanently change these values, not only in your included file.

```
- setup:
```

A better solution might be to simply run the `shell` module and ask for `whoami`:

```
- shell: whoami
  register: whoami

- debug: msg="{{ whoami.stdout }}"
```